# Prove a property of inner product with respect to second derivative of smooth map

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Consider a smooth diffeomorphism $f: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ (but not linear). At a point p, we have Euclidean inner product $\langle d_p f(v), d_p^2 f(v, w)\rangle = 0$ for all $v, w \in T_p R^n$, can we prove that $d_p^2 f(v, w) = 0$?

Here $d_p^2 f(v, w)$ is just second derivative of $f$ with respect to tangent vector $v, w$ at point p which also gives a vector. $d_p f(v)$ gives a tangent vector at $f(p)$

Comment: What if $f$ has a nondegenerate critical point at $p$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you. I change the condition to diffeomorphism. Here if critical point means that Jacobian is not invertible, then this might suffice.

Comment: I think the calculus here is a red herring. It’s just a question about symmetric bilinear forms.